# PHP Return Static Class

Tags: php, oop, instance, static-methods

I'm building a plugin interface to a [micro-framework I've been working on](https://github.com/cillosis/iceberg) and am trying to work through a conceptual problem. The first "plugin" I've decided to make is a Stripe integration, essentially taking the PHP library for Stripe and wrapping it as a Plugin. I have a sort of *factory pattern* which allows retrieval of plugin instances like:

```
$stripe = Iceberg::getPlugin('Stripe');
```

Simple enough in the event that a class can be instantiated, but for the Stripe library, all of the classes are **static**. In their examples, they recommend doing an `include()` of the main Stripe file, and then you can use it like:

```
Stripe::setApiKey('xyz');
```

My disconnect is how I can make my `getPlugin()` method work with classes that only expose static interfaces. I obviously cannot instantiate the class and expect it to work correctly, but at the same time, I want this method to work regardless of instance or static objects.

One idea I've had is to implement a `__call()` method in my Stripe Plugin class, and then try to pass those calls to the Stripe library statically, like:

**In Controller using Plugin**

```
$stripe = Iceberg::getPlugin('Stripe');
$stripe->setApiKey('xyz');
```

**In Plugin**

```
public function __call( $name, $arguments ) 
{
    Stripe::$name($arguments);
}
```

I'm not sure if something like that would even work, and even if it would, if that would be the best way.

**TLDR:** How can I create an object that can interface with classes in both object contexts and static contexts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__call` forwarding should work, as long as you forward the arguments correctly:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments) 
{
    return call_user_func_array(['Stripe', $name], $arguments);
}
```

In general this might be problematic because your plugin looks like it is instance-based, when in reality it is not (state is shared among all instances because it's `static` behind the scenes). In your case that might not really be an issue as `Iceberg::getPlugin` is probably documented to return the same instance every time for each distinct plugin name.

That said, your problem here stems from the fact that the Stripe library authors made the rookie mistake of making the library static, which leads to all kinds of problems (shared state, hard to mock the library for unit testing).

**Don't make the same mistake yourself:** lose all public static members from `Iceberg`. If someone wants ultra-convenient access to your services they can always do this:

```
function Iceberg() {
    static $instance;
    if ($instance === null) $instance = new Iceberg();
    return $instance;
}
```

They can now write `Iceberg()->foo()` just like they would write `Iceberg::foo()` before, and you as the framework author can develop enjoying the benefits of a non-static architecture. Your future self and your users will thank you for it.

Comment: Right, all plugins implement the `Plugin` abstract. The goal is to abstract the *static* calls so as far as the user knows, they just call a method on an instance and it works.

Comment: That's a really good idea Jon, thanks for the architecture advice! I realize there are a bazillion PHP frameworks, I'm just using this project as a way to practice a full implementation.